# Vim experts: how to find a number within a range based on two numbers? Eg "777" matches "667:888"

Tags: vim, regex, gvim, vim-plugins

I need to search for numbers in a text with Vim. The numbers I need to find are often within a range based on two numbers and I need to match that range based on a single number.

For example, in my file I have three lines:

> lorem ipsum 2100:2340 dolor
>
> lorem ipsum 17430:17437
>
> 53 foo bar

Searching for `2277` will match `2100:2340` because it's >= `2100` and <= `2340`. Searching for `53` will match `53` on the line with `foo bar`.

The ranges always have the greater number on the right, eg 200:100 is not a valid range in this case. There will be several ranges on the same line.

**How can this be done with Vim?**

(The reason for not using other tools is simply because I work with Vim, I love Vim and I need to use this often combined with editing the lines. Using some shell script wouldn't be effective enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Search for `\<42\>\|\<\d\+:\d\+\>`. That will capture both the exact number (`42`) and any ranges.
2. Grab the current match (`expand('<cWORD>')`).
3. If it's not the exact number, parse into start and end number (`split(range, ':')`).
4. Compare the exact number with the start and end to determine whether it falls inside it.
5. Report the result and continue searching.